# Tips first and then tricks or vice versa?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

iOS app contains "Tricks and tips" item in the "About this app" window:

> [image: menu]

After tapping on it, resulting window has a title "Tips & Tricks":

> [image: result]

I think they should be fixed for consistency.

- App Version: 1.6.3.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Tips and Tricks appear to be the correct term. [41M Google results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22tips+and+tricks%22) compared to only [400K results for Tricks and Tips](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22tricks+and+tips%22).

Comment: Tips and Tricks seems to be the *de facto* standard to me too.

Comment: There’s no “de facto *standard*”, it’s merely a common phrasing. That doesn’t necessarily mean you have to adhere to it. Obviously, this syntax did draw some attention it probably would not have drawn otherwise. So it’s debatable if it’s set like this on purpose.

Comment: @dakab most likely an oversight by the developer who didn't really pay attention to it, I've asked him in chat, hopefully he will reply soon. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what happened there.  Fixing.

Comment: coffee of lack?